# Example of a set with empty boundary in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

I was dealing with a problem, if subset of a metric space has empty boundary then it is open as well as closed in the space. The proof is easy. But I am wondering for a nontrivial example of such set (which has empty boundary).

Since $\Bbb{R}$ is connected, so in $\Bbb{R}$ there is not any such. Then if we take a disconnect subspace of $\Bbb{R}$ then easily we get an example. Can any body give an example of subset with empty boundary in the disconnect subspace $\Bbb{Q}$ of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: Consider the subspace $\{1\}$ of $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap (-\infty, \sqrt{2})$. It is both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.